# Why will $_POST work for some files and not for others

Tags: php, html, forms, post

This is my code where the user submits data.

```
<form action="PSBE_RESULTS.php" method="post">
Search By: 
<select name="searchtype" size="1">
<option value="author">Author</option>
<option value="class">Class</option>
<option value="isbn">ISBN</option>    
<option value="title">Title</option>
</select>
    <br/>
    <br/>

Enter Search Term:
<input type="text" name="searchterm" size="30" maxlength="100" />
<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

This is where the results are displayed:

```
$searchtype = $_POST['searchtype'];
$searchterm = $_POST['searchterm'];

echo "$searchtype";
echo "$searchterm";

$a = var_dump($_POST);
echo $a;
```

Nothing shows up. Absolutely nothing. The weird thing is that this problem occurred to me earlier today and I changed **$_POST** to **$_REQUEST** and then I changed it back to **$_POST**. For some reason my code starting working again until now. I tried this again but it did not work. Also, I have other files which use the **$_POST** and those files work perfectly. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: does `print_r($_POST);` show anything? are you sure its the right file "PSBE_RESULTS.php" ?

Comment: The php code you mentioned, is that in the PSBE_RESULTS.php or are you header redirecting to that code?

Comment: as a note you dont need to assign `var_dump` to a variable and then `echo` it. Just do `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: @Dagon That function does not show anything either and I am 100% sure that's the right file. It was working before. It just stopped suddenly.

Comment: if it shows NOTHING your looking ar the wrong file it will at least show an empty `array()`

Comment: @MajorCaiger The latter code is in PSBE_RESULTS.php

Comment: Close your form tag `</form>`. Also, at the very top of your results php file, do something like `var_dump($_POST['searchtype']);exit;` and if you still don't see anything, there is probably a php syntax error that's killing everything.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` only, no assignment, and put it at top of file first thing after `<?php`

Comment: @snowman4415 Sorry, the form was closed, I forgot to type it in. After adding that code I got something to display. Does that mean $_POST is working?

Comment: depends what the "something" is

Comment: @user3826764 that means your form is being hit correctly, so there's probably an error further down the page. If I were you I'd take that line of code and move it down the page until it stops showing up, and then you know the error is right above it. A little hack but a good trick for debugging without error messages.

Comment: $dagon. I picked author for the first option and my search term was apple. What was displayed was:  string(6) "author" .

Comment: POST is working, its something 'else' carry on.

Comment: @snowman4415 That trick did it. I had a require_once file that held the information to access my database at the top. After taking that out, the code started working. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are written method='post' in form so it working with only post method